# how humanInstance.hasErrors() perform in save action in grails 2.3.0 controller both rest and normal

Tags: grails

```
if (humanInstance.hasErrors()) {
   respond humanInstance.errors, view:'create'
   return
   //Explain : here after  respond we see two parameter
   //When save call from rest url if error happen it show JSON like below
   //Question: so what is the function of  view:'create'  when i call from rest?
   //{"errors":[{"object":"learn.Human","field":"name","rejected-value":null,"message":"Property [name] of class [class learn.Human] cannot be null"}]}
}
```

Comment: I do not know what is really being asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so little to work with there that it is hard to say what your real problem but to answer the specific question cited in the post...

> what is the function of  view:'create'  when i call from rest?

The view attribute there is saying that if HTML is being rendered, render the 'create' view.

The JSON you show there suggests that humanInstance is probably an instance of the learn.Human class, that class defines a property named "name" and the instance was validated while the value of the "name" property was null.  It isn't clear from the snippet you showed if humanInstance is a command object or if you created the instance yourself and what data was used to populate the instance.  It is impossible to say without seeing more code but one thing that might have happened is maybe humanInstance is a command object and the request parameters or request body did not contain a value for the "name" property.

Comment: your answer is nice ... but I think I did not clear you my question ... I will post another question later on this topic . thank u so much, Jeff

Comment: It may be that I misunderstood what you meant by "so what is the function of  view:'create'".  Best of luck.